# how to go to specific slide on leftChevron click in bootstrap carousel instead of going to immediate previous slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Carousel control.
Now I am also maintaining a java script collection and array like below:
Now this is how the carousel is rendered in UI:

```
 <div class="carousel slide " id="divFormCarousel" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="active" onclick="SetSaveAndNext()" data-target="#divFormCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li onclick="SetSaveAndNext()" data-target="#divFormCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li onclick="SetFinish()" data-target="#divFormCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active" id="101">
      <form id="frmConsentForm+101" method="post" data-url="/Forms/Save">
     </form>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="102">
      <form id="frmConsentForm+102" method="post" data-url="/Forms/Save"> 
     </form>
     </div>
      <div class="item" id="404">         
      <form id="frmConsentForm+404" method="post" data-url="/Forms/Save"></form>
      </div>        
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="leftChevron" style="margin-left: -90px; filter: none;" href="#divPatientFormCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control hidden-xs hidden-sm  hidden-md hidden-lg" id="rightChevron" style="margin-right: -90px; filter: none;" href="#divPatientFormCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Now as we know:

```
$('#leftChevron').trigger('click'); //This actually helps us to slide to the previous slide, which s working fine!
```

But what I want to implement here is based on the array and the collection defined below, lets say I am at slide with id 404 , when I click on the previous button(which internally calls the leftChevron click), I want to redirect to that slide (which meets some criteria, defined below)not the exact previous slide.The criteria is:
when I click btnPrevious,based on the collection and the array redirect to that form for which forms[id]=0 and not 1.

forms = {};//Collection which stores the formid and their corresponding status.So it is like forms[101]="0",forms[102]="1",forms[404]="0"
    formsarray = [];//this stores the formid, like formsarray[0]=101. formsarray[1]=102, formsarray[2]=404

Basically, using JQuery,I think it should be a simple fix, so any help will be highly appretiated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap Carousel has an [API](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-methods) for this. If you know which page you need to scroll to, you just simple need to call:

```
$div.carousel(pageNumber);
```

*(Replace $div with your jQuery selector.)*

By the way, instead of clicking on the `#leftChevron` or `#rightChevron`, you can also use the correct API methods:

```
$div.carousel('prev');
```

and

```
$div.carousel('next');
```